# Piezo cantilever energy harvester: how to mesure such small power?

Tags: arduino, low-power, energy, piezo

I am currently designing a piezo energy harvester and I would like to modify the resonating frequency to maximize the energy recovered(for exemple by changing the center of mass of the cantilever). My issue is to know how to sense the actual power drawn by the load, and as you might know it is very small with such devices. Then with a microcontroller I should be able to adjust the resonating frequency.

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Just measure the voltage. Presumably you know the load impedance; so you can compute power from that.

Comment: What is the range of frequencies?

Comment: What's stopping you running at maximum efficiency (i.e. fixed tuning and no messing about with ugly MCU tuning) and using a micropower voltage regulator afterwards?

Comment: @BrianDrummond you're totally wright I will do my experiment with a fixed impedence load... thanks

Comment: @ThePhoton I hope to have a range of 30Hz to 70Hz

Comment: @Andyaka in fact I expect the frequency to change so i can't use a fixed tuning. But I maybe not well understand what is MCU tunning...

Comment: Microprocessor/microcontroller tuning. Trying to tune a piezo between 30 Hz and 70 Hz sounds very problematic. Anyway, I think you question isn't properly revealing itself to me so I'll say no more.

Comment: Repeating with several known load impedances is probably useful.

Comment: @Andyaka sorry i did not say the most important, it is a cantilever piezo harvester. The resonating frequency is the frequency of a piezo electric beam. I'll be adjusting it by moving a center of mass or changing the length of it.

Comment: @BrianDrummond To increase precision of the measure?

Comment: Yes that is important in-fact so important that you must put those words in the question.

Comment: @Andyaka I will think about it for a later question, it is my first time on this forum...

Comment: No, fix your question so that others (like me) do not have their time wasted exploring what you might mean.

Comment: @Andyaka Done! ...

Comment: What strikes me about it now is that moving the mass uses energy and that seems to require some form of motor (if controlled from a micro) and that means there's a really good chance then you will use more power making the system "resonant" than what you get from the harvesting. I think you need to explain how this can be avoided so that anyone answering will actually take this question seriously (as opposed to some daft perpetual motion idea).

Comment: @Andyaka I am aware of that and i still need to find if the energy cost is not too high. An option is to create a system that wakes up every fixed time to tune the piezo and the go back in low consumption mode after. I think that a good balance can be find if the source frequency does not vary too much in time.

Comment: @AndrieuxTheo I doubt the microcontroller running continously would be a large consumer of power – actuating something with a motor will eat hours if not days of microcontroller energy consumption. "I think that a good balance...": Math this out first roughly, before doing a design for something that energetically can't work out.